# Visualizing self-organizing maps in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, self-organizing-maps

is there any python package that deals with visualizing and animating unsupervised-learning networks, i.e. like self-organizing maps (SOM)?
hoping if matplotlib have code for it.

Comment: Context would be useful.

Comment: Where you mean @GamesBrainiac? excuse me, but am new to Stackoverflow, and i don't know whether you comment is positive of negative.

Comment: Things like what have you tried (what libraries in matplotlib), and what do you hope to make?

Comment: Well, I am new to Python and the open-source world, i have a seminar on SOM, and i want to illustrate it as simple and clear as possible using Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use matplotlib, have a look at how to plot a confusion matrix:

[How to plot confusion matrix with string axis rather than integer in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821125/how-to-plot-confusion-matrix-with-string-axis-rather-than-integer-in-python)

Plotting a 2D SOM should be a similar task.