# How can I plot a confusion matrix?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, scikit-learn, text-classification

I am using scikit-learn for classification of text documents(22000) to 100 classes. I use scikit-learn's confusion matrix method for computing the confusion matrix.

```
model1 = LogisticRegression()
model1 = model1.fit(matrix, labels)
pred = model1.predict(test_matrix)
cm=metrics.confusion_matrix(test_labels,pred)
print(cm)
plt.imshow(cm, cmap='binary')
```

This is how my confusion matrix looks like:

```
[[3962  325    0 ...,    0    0    0]
 [ 250 2765    0 ...,    0    0    0]
 [   2    8   17 ...,    0    0    0]
 ..., 
 [   1    6    0 ...,    5    0    0]
 [   1    1    0 ...,    0    0    0]
 [   9    0    0 ...,    0    0    9]]
```

However, I do not receive a clear or legible plot. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74152927/3322273) for pure Matplotlib code

Answer (score 237):

[image]

you can use `plt.matshow()` instead of `plt.imshow()` or you can use seaborn module's `heatmap` ([see documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)) to plot the confusion matrix

```
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
array = [[33,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3], 
        [3,31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
        [0,4,41,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], 
        [0,1,0,30,0,6,0,0,0,0,1], 
        [0,0,0,0,38,10,0,0,0,0,0], 
        [0,0,0,3,1,39,0,0,0,0,4], 
        [0,2,2,0,4,1,31,0,0,0,2],
        [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,36,0,2,0], 
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,37,5,1], 
        [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,0], 
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,38]]
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, index = [i for i in "ABCDEFGHIJK"],
                  columns = [i for i in "ABCDEFGHIJK"])
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True)
```

Comment: mask_bad = X.mask if np.ma.is_masked(X) else np.isnan(X)  # Mask nan's.
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: If there are numbers with 3 or more digits this prints them in normal form like `3.4e+02` for 340, due to the default `fmt` parameter. Setting it to like `sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, fmt='.10g')` fixes this.

Answer (score 127):

@bninopaul 's answer is not completely for beginners

here is the code you can "copy and run"

```
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = [[13,1,1,0,2,0],
         [3,9,6,0,1,0],
         [0,0,16,2,0,0],
         [0,0,0,13,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0,15,0],
         [0,0,1,0,0,15]]

df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, range(6), range(6))
# plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
sn.set(font_scale=1.4) # for label size
sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 16}) # font size

plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Just to add, for custom `x` and `y` labels, replace `df_cm` line with something like this: `df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, index=["stage 1", "stage 2", "stage 3", "stagte 4"], columns=["stage 1", "stage 2", "stage 3", "stagte 4"])`

Comment: I'm not seeing why this answer is more "for beginners"?... It's basically the same as bninopaul's.

Comment: The conf matrix is *beginner-sized*   @DavidSkarbrevik  ;)

Answer (score 80):

IF you want **more data** in you confusion matrix, including "**totals column**" and "**totals line**", and **percents** (%) in each cell, *like matlab default* (see image below)

[image]

including the Heatmap and other options...

You should have fun with the module above, shared in the github  ; )

https://github.com/wcipriano/pretty-print-confusion-matrix

---

This module can do your task easily and produces the output above with a lot of params to customize your CM:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! Can you approve this PR, pip installing would be so much nicer: https://github.com/wcipriano/pretty-print-confusion-matrix/pull/11

Comment: hello Ian! Okay, I'll check and approve your PR, thanks for collaboration  ; )

Comment: Wasn't my PR, but thank you for approving! :)

Comment: Okay, It was PR 11 (Make the package available to be installed via PyPI).
I saw this cause of your comment here in this thread, thanks!