# How to plot probability of a particular class in random forest classifier vs recall in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, random-forest

I am trying tune my random forest classifier to maximize the recall . How can I can plot Probability vs Recall in Pandas dataframe.

**My current code to print the classification report**

```
from sklearn import metrics
predicted_randomforest = fit_rf.predict_proba(df1)
predictions=pd.DataFrame(predicted_randomforest)
predictions['outcome'] = np.where(predictions[0]>=0.85,0,1)
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(Y_test, predictions['outcome']))
print(np.mean(predictions['outcome'] == Y_test) )
target_names=['Business','Resi']
print(classification_report(Y_test,predictions['outcome'],target_names=target_names))
```

**Output**

```
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

   Business       1.00      0.96      0.98     76742
       Resi       0.73      0.97      0.83      8442

avg / total       0.97      0.96      0.96     85184
```

I want plot Probability in x -axis and recall value in Y- axis.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure about your goal? Do you mind to sketch the plot are you looking for? Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35572000/4819376) could offer you some insight.

Comment: @user32185, I want  to plot how each change  probability ( 0 to 1) class 0  is affecting the change the recall of class 1. In short I want to plot  Probabilty values on x - axis and recall value of class 1 in  Y axis ( 0 to 1).

Comment: It might be worth checking sklearn's roc_curve() - it returns true positve and false positive rate and also probability thresholds and you can plot these. You would need to invoke the .predict_proba() method of your classifier first in order to calculate predicted probabilities and then pass them to  roc_curve along with y_test.

Comment: @KRKirov,I have  already calculated predict_proba  . its der in the code

Comment: OK, so you have done the first step. Have you checked the documentation for roc_curve. This might be close to what you are trying to achieve. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html