# incorrect confusion matrix plot

Tags: seaborn, confusion-matrix

The ends on y-axis cuts halfway while plotting confusion matrix using pandas dataframe?

This is what I get:

[image: Click to see the plot]

I used the codes from here [How can I plot a confusion matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572000/how-can-i-plot-a-confusion-matrix) using pandas dataframe:

```
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = [[13,1,1,0,2,0],
    [3,9,6,0,1,0],
    [0,0,16,2,0,0],
    [0,0,0,13,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,15,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,15]]        
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, range(6),range(6))
#plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
sn.set(font_scale=1.4)#for label size
sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True,annot_kws={"size": 16})# font size
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem and I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942670/matplotlib-seaborn-first-and-last-row-cut-in-half-of-heatmap-plot) explains why it happens.

Simply speaking, matplotlib 3.1.1 broke seaborn heatmaps; You can solve it by downgrading to matplotlib 3.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [sikisis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2194352/sikisis)

Following solved my problem

`pip install matplotlib==3.1.0`