# Jupyter Notebook plots cut off on top and bottom

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I've been trying to plot a confusion matrix in Jupyter notebook. No matter which library I use (matplotlib/scikit-learn/seaborn), the top and bottom of the plot is cut off. I tried creating a fresh notebook and it happens there too. I can't figure out what's causing this?

[Link to screenshot (I was not allowed to embed image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvgOZ.png)

This screenshot is from running unmodified toy example:

```
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
array = [[33,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3], 
    [3,31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
    [0,4,41,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], 
    [0,1,0,30,0,6,0,0,0,0,1], 
    [0,0,0,0,38,10,0,0,0,0,0], 
    [0,0,0,3,1,39,0,0,0,0,4], 
    [0,2,2,0,4,1,31,0,0,0,2],
    [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,36,0,2,0], 
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,37,5,1], 
    [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,0], 
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,38]]
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, index = [i for i in "ABCDEFGHIJK"],
              columns = [i for i in "ABCDEFGHIJK"])
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True)
```

Source of code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35572247/11998193

Comment: Hi, @tiko93, did you figure it out? I am also experiencing the same issue here.