# Incomplete graph in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

Good day to all,

2 weeks ago my pyplots graph were working good. Hoever this week using the same code they are not plotting corectly on the y_axis. I thank you in advance all the help. Please find below a link to an example notebook as well as the example code I took from here [2], using seabrone library.

On the following picture you can see that the first and last row are incomplete.

[image: incomplete plot]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1My18DBfbTLsmeN2TxKYeFMkezXMGeb5W

Or you can copy the following code:

```
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
array = [[33,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3], 
        [3,31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
        [0,4,41,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], 
        [0,1,0,30,0,6,0,0,0,0,1], 
        [0,0,0,0,38,10,0,0,0,0,0], 
        [0,0,0,3,1,39,0,0,0,0,4], 
        [0,2,2,0,4,1,31,0,0,0,2],
        [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,36,0,2,0], 
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,37,5,1], 
        [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,0], 
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,38]]
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array, index = [i for i in "ABCDEFGHIJK"],
                  columns = [i for i in "ABCDEFGHIJK"])
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True)

## Retrieved from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572000/how-can-i-plot-a-confusion-matrix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved it or at least I found the reason of the problem. There was an update of matplotlib. The lastest version is 3.1.1 and I was using 3.1.0. So I used the following command to install the 3.1.0 version on colab. After that everything went back to normal

```
#This was the code for changing the matplotlib version in Google Colab:
! pip install matplotlib==3.1.0
```