# Input 0 of layer lstm_9 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 300, 300, 1]

Tags: python, keras

The code is exectuted over the  image dataset and on execution of the below code i am getting the value error.Help me to figure out how to fix this error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, LSTM
import pickle
import numpy as np

X = np.array(pickle.load(open("X.pickle","rb")))
Y = np.array(pickle.load(open("Y.pickle","rb")))

#scaling our image data
X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)
#model.add(Conv2D(64 ,(3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Conv2D(64 ,(3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
# print(X.shape)
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

model.add(Conv2D(128 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

model.add(Conv2D(256 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

model.add(Conv2D(512 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

model.add(Flatten())
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X.shape[1:]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=32, epochs = 2, validation_split=0.1)
```

The above code produces following outputs. I was printing shape again and to again just to see the resultant matrix. 
(90, 300, 300, 1)
(90,)
(90, 300, 300, 1)
(90,)
(90, 300, 300, 1)
(90,)
(90, 300, 300, 1)
(90,)
(90, 300, 300, 1)
(90,)
(90, 300, 300, 1)
(90,)

Here a very small change is needed in input dimension of an image in the first LSTM as per the error in the code. Can you please make changes into the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64 ,(3,3), input_shape = (300,300,1)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(512 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Reshape((16, 16*512)))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Comment: Is there any way I can apply both CNN and LSTM in one code because what you are suggesting is just CNN and I want to use a hybrid of these?

Comment: I edited, please don't forget to upvote and accept it as answer

Comment: Can you please make changes in the above code. I edited my code.

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much! But is it possible to print the accuracy and confusion matrix of the model?

Comment: for accuracy: model.evaluate(X_test) while the conf matrix can be made with sklearn

Comment: for evaluate I need to use placeholders in tensorflow. Right?

Comment: In simple cases placeholder is not needed, you can simply call evaluate

Comment: Is it possible to get confusion matrix out of it and graphs of the results? If yes, then how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572000/how-can-i-plot-a-confusion-matrix

Comment: They have used test data but in my case I had not splitted the data into train and test set similarly what should be pass to the model.evaluate function.I am new to python and ML please help me out.

Comment: please, make a new question