# Is it possible to make a confusion matrix from character pairs?

Tags: python-3.x

In the context of optical character recognition, I will try to summarize my issue at best :

1. I have reference sentence and a prediction sentence.
2. With [Levenshtein editops function](https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html), I made a list that contains a tuple which contains : a step type (insertion, replace, substitution), the character modified in reference sequence, a character modified in a prediction sequence, and finally the number of times these changes are made in all of the reference sentence (in fact, maximum number of occurrences where these pairs of errors return)

```
[(('insert', 'e', 'm'), 11), (('insert', 't', 'a'), 8), (('insert', 'r', 'o'), 5), (('replace', 'a', 'e'), 2), (('replace', 't', 'T'), 1), (('replace', 'r', 'R'), 1), (('replace', 'M', 'm'), 1), (('delete', ' ', 'a'), 1), (('replace', 'p', 'o'), 1), (('replace', 't', 'a'), 1), (('replace', 'e', 'e'), 1), (('replace', ' ', 'r'), 1), (('insert', ' ', 'd'), 1), (('replace', ' ', 'd'), 1), (('replace', 'i', 'e'), 1), (('replace', 'l', 's'), 1)]
```

3. Is it possible to make a sort of "confusion matrix" with these pairs of errors and maximum number of occurrences, from the previous list ? like this :

**Output example**

```
Predicted         e         m         t          a        r   ...continue
Reference
e                 1         11        0          0        0
m                 0         0         0          0        0
t                 0         0         0          8        0 
a                 2         0         0          0        0
r                 0         0         0          0        0
...continue
```

or like this (without labels):

```
[[1         11        0          0        0
  0         0         0          0        0
  0         0         0          8        0 
  2         0         0          0        0
  0         0         0          0        0]]
```

Note : the value 0 is replaced by default in this 'matrix' examples when a character error pair is not encountered.

4. in a second time, is it possible to obtain a visualization of this 'matrix'? with matplotlib or seaborn, for example.

a track to solve it ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with Counters:

```
operations = [(('insert', 'e', 'm'), 11), (('insert', 't', 'a'), 8), (('insert', 'r', 'o'), 5), (('replace', 'a', 'e'), 2), (('replace', 't', 'T'), 1), (('replace', 'r', 'R'), 1), (('replace', 'M', 'm'), 1), (('delete', ' ', 'a'), 1), (('replace', 'p', 'o'), 1), (('replace', 't', 'a'), 1), (('replace', 'e', 'e'), 1), (('replace', ' ', 'r'), 1), (('insert', ' ', 'd'), 1), (('replace', ' ', 'd'), 1), (('replace', 'i', 'e'), 1), (('replace', 'l', 's'), 1)]

from collections import defaultdict, Counter

intermediary = defaultdict(Counter)
for (_, src, tgt), count in source:
    intermediary[src][tgt] = count

letters = sorted({key for inner in intermediary.values() for key in inner} | set(intermediary.keys()))

confusion_matrix = [[intermediary[src][tgt] for tgt in letters] for src in letters]
```

The result looks something like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

For plotting, refer to [the answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572000/how-can-i-plot-a-confusion-matrix):

```
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_cm = pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix, letters, letters)
sn.set(font_scale=1.4) # for label size
sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 16}) # font size

plt.show()
```

Comment: it works perfectly, it should be written in a recipe book. Thanks for your help !