# Display an image with pixel values shown numerically

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm looking for OpenCV or other Python function that displays a NumPy array as an image like this:

[image]

Referenced from [this tutorial](http://datahacker.rs/002-opencv-projects-how-to-cartoonize-an-image-with-opencv-in-python).

- What function creates this kind of grey-scale image with pixel values display?
- Is there a color image equivalent?

MATLAB has a function called [`showPixelValues()`](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14142-display-pixels-and-pixel-values).

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this. For example, [plot it as a heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572000/how-can-i-plot-a-confusion-matrix) and you will get the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Seaborn does it directly at the cost of one more package. "heat map" is a good search term, and here's an example using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html)

Comment: so the problem solved ?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to search "heat map" or "confusion matrix" rather than image, then there are two good options:

1. Using `matplotlib` only, with `imshow()` and `text()` as building blocks the solution is actually not that hard, and here are [some examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html).
2. Using [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org) which is a data visualisation package and the solution is essentially a one-liner using [`seaborn.heatmap()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html?highlight=heatmap#seaborn.heatmap) as shown in [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572000/how-can-i-plot-a-confusion-matrix).

My problem was really tunnel vision, coming at it from an image processing mindset, and not thinking about what other communities have a need to display the same thing even if they call it by a different name.

Answer (score 1):

Using matplotlib you could do something like:

```
image = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(10, 10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(image, cmap='gray')

for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        ax.text(j, i, str(image[i, j]), color='r', ha='center', va='center')
```

It will produce the following image:

[image: Image with pixel intensities]

By the way, if you want to stick to grayscale only, you might want to try something like:

```
for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        c = 1 if image[i, j] < 128 else 0
        ax.text(j, i, str(image[i, j]), color=(c, c, c), ha='center', va='center')
        ax.axis("off")
```

Resulting in:

[image]