# How to make a Confusion Matrix with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, confusion-matrix

I have trained my model (multiclass classification) of CNN using keras and now I want to evaluate the model on my test set of images. Is there a way to create confusion matrix?

Comment: Please notice that you do (and should) not need to post a [wall of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/) in order to ask how to calculate a confusion matrix; posting your predictions and the respective ground truth should be nore than enough - please see how to create a [mre] (emphasis on *minimal*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for answers. I did like this:

```
#Predict
y_prediction = model.predict(x_test)
y_prediction = np.argmax (y_prediction, axis = 1)
y_test=np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
#Create confusion matrix and normalizes it over predicted (columns)
result = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_prediction , normalize='pred')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use sklearn for that.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

#Predict
y_prediction = model.predict(x_test)

#Create confusion matrix and normalizes it over predicted (columns)
result = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_prediction , normalize='pred')
```

If you want to plot it as well, you can find several ways here: [How can I plot a confusion matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572000/how-can-i-plot-a-confusion-matrix)

Comment: Are you sure from OP's description that both `y_test` and `y_prediction` are single-digit predictions, and not one-hot encoded vectors (in which case `confusion_matrix` will simply not work)?

Comment: I got an error  - ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets