# How to plot confusion matrix with gridding without color using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I found a similar quesion on [How to plot confusion matrix with string axis rather than integer in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821125/how-to-plot-confusion-matrix-with-string-axis-rather-than-integer-in-python). But the answer is not exact what I want. Because it doesn't contain gridding (e.g., the numbers are not in little squares) and there is background color to show the number which is not what I want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

conf_arr = [[33,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3], 
            [3,31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
            [0,4,41,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], 
            [0,1,0,30,0,6,0,0,0,0,1], 
            [0,0,0,0,38,10,0,0,0,0,0], 
            [0,0,0,3,1,39,0,0,0,0,4], 
            [0,2,2,0,4,1,31,0,0,0,2],
            [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,36,0,2,0], 
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,37,5,1], 
            [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,0], 
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,38]]

norm_conf = []
for i in conf_arr:
    a = 0
    tmp_arr = []
    a = sum(i, 0)
    for j in i:
        tmp_arr.append(float(j)/float(a))
    norm_conf.append(tmp_arr)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.clf()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect(1)
res = ax.imshow(np.array(norm_conf), cmap=plt.cm.jet, 
                interpolation='nearest')

width, height = conf_arr.shape

for x in xrange(width):
    for y in xrange(height):
        ax.annotate(str(conf_arr[x][y]), xy=(y, x), 
                    horizontalalignment='center',
                    verticalalignment='center')

cb = fig.colorbar(res)
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
plt.xticks(range(width), alphabet[:width])
plt.yticks(range(height), alphabet[:height])
plt.savefig('confusion_matrix.png', format='png')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making only a few changes to that rather excellent code proposal (I upvoted it, consider doing that too), you can get the figure you're describing.

You'll get gridding by calling the `hlines` and `vlines` methods of the `ax` object, which will add horizontal and vertical lines respectively.
When you then also remove the call to `imshow`, the colors are gone. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

conf_arr = np.array([[33,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3], 
            [3,31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
            [0,4,41,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], 
            [0,1,0,30,0,6,0,0,0,0,1], 
            [0,0,0,0,38,10,0,0,0,0,0], 
            [0,0,0,3,1,39,0,0,0,0,4], 
            [0,2,2,0,4,1,31,0,0,0,2],
            [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,36,0,2,0], 
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,37,5,1], 
            [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,0], 
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,38]])
height, width = conf_arr.shape

fig = plt.figure('confusion matrix')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        ax.annotate(str(conf_arr[x][y]), xy=(y, x), ha='center', va='center')

offset = .5    
ax.set_xlim(-offset, width - offset)
ax.set_ylim(-offset, height - offset)

ax.hlines(y=np.arange(height+1)- offset, xmin=-offset, xmax=width-offset)
ax.vlines(x=np.arange(width+1) - offset, ymin=-offset, ymax=height-offset)

alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
plt.xticks(range(width), alphabet[:width])
plt.yticks(range(height), alphabet[:height])
plt.savefig('confusion_matrix.png', format='png')
```

[image: example of gridded confusion matrix without colors]

Remark that when you remove the call to `imshow`, you'll need to set the x- and y-limits explicitly, as shown above, otherwise you'll only see the lower left region (`imshow` updates the limits automatically depending on what you pass to it).